# PHP/MySql sorting issue

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have problem with my php sorting...
I use _SESSION because I want to store sorting for another page, I think it's right.
This is my code:

```
  <?php     
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies";
                $_SESSION['sort'] = isset($_GET['sort']);

                        if (isset ($_SESSION['sort']) == 'Year')
                        {
                            $sql .= " ORDER BY year";
                        }
                        elseif (isset($_SESSION['sort']) == 'IMDB')
                        {
                            $sql .= " ORDER BY IMDBrating";
                        }
                        elseif (isset($_SESSION['sort']) == 'user')
                        {
                            $sql .= " ORDER BY userrating";
                        }               

            ?>

                <select name="sort" id="sort" tabindex="1">
                    <option value="Year">Year</option>
                    <option value="IMDB">IMDB rating</option>
                    <option value="user">user rating</option>
                </select>

<?php
            $pagesize = 5;

            $recordstart = (int)(isset($_GET['recordstart'])) ? $_GET['recordstart'] : 0;

            $sql01 = "SELECT * FROM movies LIMIT $recordstart, $pagesize";
            $records=mysql_query($sql01);

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM movies");
            $totalrows = mysql_fetch_row($result);

            while ($movies=mysql_fetch_array($records)){
                echo '<div class="movie_box"><p><div class="news_img"><div class="cover"><img src="'.$movies['cover'].'" width = "183px" height = "271px"/></div><br><button class="trailer_button" type="button">Trailer</button></div><strong><p class="h3"><div class="content">'.$movies['name'].'</p></strong>'.$movies['plot'].'<br><br><strong>Žanr</strong>:'.$movies['genre'].'<br><strong>IMDB ocjena</strong>:'.$movies['IMDBrating'].'<br><strong>Director</strong>:'.$movies['director'].'<br><strong>Glumci</strong>:'.$movies['Starring'].'<br><strong>Ocjena korisnika</strong>:</div><br><div class="trailer">'.$movies['trailer'].'</div><div class="dark"></div></p></div>';
            }

            if ($recordstart > 0){
                $prev = $recordstart - $pagesize;
                $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?recordstart='.$prev;
                printf('<a id="prev" href="%s"><</a>',$url);
            }

            if ($totalrows > ($recordstart + $pagesize)){
                $next = $recordstart + $pagesize;
                $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?recordstart='.$next;
                printf('<a id="next" href="%s">></a>',$url);
            }

        ?>
```

There is no error but still no sorting.
Now I edit post and you can see another part with another page script.

Comment: You never actually execute your SQL statement?  Where specifically does this fail?  When you debug this, what is the actual SQL statement being executed and what are the results?

Comment: Echo out the `$sql` and post it back here. Also, that code doesn't show any queries being made.

Comment: @N.B. When i echo #sql it says SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY year

Comment: Great, and where do you query MySQL with that? The code shows only that you created the `$sql` string, but no queries are being made. Is that the entire code?

Comment: Your use of `isset()` is confusing and awkward.  And I suspect it will *always* result in the first `if` block always being `true`.

Comment: @N.B. `if (isset ($_SESSION['sort']) == 'Year')
     {
      $sql .= " ORDER BY year";
     }
     elseif (isset($_SESSION['sort']) == 'IMDB')
     {
      $sql .= " ORDER BY IMDBrating";
     }
     elseif (isset($_SESSION['sort']) == 'user')
     {
      $sql .= " ORDER BY userrating";
     } ` here i use $sql

Answer (score 2):

`isset()` returns a boolean, either `true` or `false`.  So this:

```
$_SESSION['sort'] = isset($_GET['sort']);
```

will set the session variable to either `true` or `false`.  Then any time you do this:

```
isset($_SESSION['sort'])
```

it will return `true` since you set that session variable.  This, however:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['sort']) == 'Year')
```

will always result in `true` because any non-null string value is "true-y".  So your code will *always* sort by year, regardless of what sort options have been specified by the user.

---

If this contains your sort specifier:

```
$_GET['sort']
```

Then you don't need to use session or `isset` like this.  Just compare that value:

```
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'Year')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY year";
}
// etc.
```

Comment: but if i don't use session, then how i can store that sort if i go to another page?

Comment: @IvanGorički: There's nothing in your code which indicates that there even *is* another page.  But yes, if you use session then you can refer to that value on another page.  Or you could use a `$_GET` query string value like you're already using.

Answer (score 1):

```
isset($_GET['sort']) == true;
```

if sort is set in _GET param, thats what isset function returns, true or false

you should do:

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
  $_SESSION['sort'] = $_GET['sort'];
} else {
 $_SESSION['sort'] = 'somekind of default sort';
}
```